# Shortcut in nano editor for adding quotation marks to every word beginning with $ in a bash script?

Tags: bash, nano

I am new to writing in bash and I just finished this long script but I made the mistake of not adding quotation marks to all the variables beginning with the unary operator `$`. Adding all the quotation marks by hand is going to take a while. Is there a short cut I can use so all the words in the text file beginning with `$` get quotation marks around them? So if a line in the file looks like:

```
python myProgram.py $car1 $car2 $speed1 $speed2
```

Then after the shortcut it will appear as

```
python myProgram.py "$car1" "$car2" "$speed1" "$speed2"
```

I am writing the script using nano.

Comment: Might be time to move up from nano.  If you don't want to take the plunge into vi(m) or emacs, you could try installing joe or mcedit.

Comment: I usually work with emacs. However, I don't have permission to install emacs on the server that I am working on right now so I have no choice. I've been told the vim has a high learning curve so I went for nano.

Comment: In that case I would edit the script somewhere you have your preferred editor and just copy it to the target machine rather than editing it in place with tools that aren't really powerful enough for the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use global search and replace with the expression `(\$\w+)`.

1. Switch to search and replace mode with `C-\`.
2. Switch to regex mode with `Alt-R`.
3. Type the expression `(\$\w+)`. Hit Enter.
4. Type in the replacement expression `"\1"` replace the captured expression with quotations. Hit Enter.
5. On the match, hit `A` for All.

Answer (score 0):

Given your need, it doesn't seem mandatory to provide a solution based on that editor. If you have access to a shell you might try this simple `sed` command:

```
sed -i.bak -r 's/\$\w+/"&"/g' my-script.sh
```

This is far from being perfect but should do the job in your particular case. If the above command:

- `-i.bak` will perform the replacement "in place" -- that is modifying the original file, making a backup with the `.bak` extension
- `s/..../..../g` is the usual `sed` command to search and replace using a *pattern*. The search pattern is between the first two `\`. The replacement is between the last two `/`
- `\$\w+` this *pattern* correspond to a `$` followed by one or more letters (`\w+`). The *backslash* before `$` is needed because that character normally has special meaning in a search pattern.
- `"&"` is the replacement string. In there, the `&` is replaced by the string found in the search pattern. Broadly speaking this put quotes arround any string matching the search pattern.

Comment: While I love `vim`, I disagree with your claim that `nano` does not support `regex`. :P

Comment: That will double-quote standalone dollar signs; `\w+` would be better.  And if you're using GNU sed (as indicated by the use of `\w`), you can just modify the file in place with `sed -i` instead of creating a new file (maybe use `sed -i.bak` to create a backup in case your command isn't quite right.)

Comment: @MarkReed Thank you for your comment. I've fixed those various ... hum ... "typos" ;)